# Python, remove comma from integer in tuple

Tags: python, tuples

how can I remove the comma from an integer in a tuple?

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT score FROM highscore WHERE userID=4")
highscore = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in highscore:
    print(x)
```

I'm fetching the numbers from a db, and this is my output

```
Output:
(324,)
(442,)
(100,)
```

Can anyone tell my how I can remove the comma in the end of the integers?
I would appreciate any help:)

Comment: Those aren't integers, they are tuples containing a single integer

Comment: this comma is there to show you that it's a tuple.

Comment: As others' said, this is to show you that it's a tuple. If you want only the integer, you can simply access the index from tuple (i.e.: `tpl[0]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the tuple. To access the value just do

```py
for x in highscore:
    print(x[0])
```

or

```py
for (x,) in highscore:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short... you can't.

That comma is used to differentiate a tuple from an int declared using the parenthesis notation, as in example:

```py
# This is an int
a = (
  2
)

# This is a tuple
b = (
  2,
)
```

If you don't want a comma, use a  list or a set, or just a single int. But a tuple with a single element inside will always have the trailing comma.